# Error with newInstanceArgs in ReflectionClass

Tags: php, zend-framework, reflection

Following script works perfectly,

```
$transport = new Amazonses_App_Mail_Transport_AmazonSES(
        array(
            'accessKey' => '*******************',
            'privateKey' => '***********************'
            )
        );
```

But, when it transfer as follows, getting error.

```
$mailConfig = array(
          'class' => 'Amazonses_App_Mail_Transport_AmazonSES',
          'args' => array( 'accessKey' => '*******************',
            'privateKey' => '***********************')
        );
 try {

        $args = ( !empty($mailConfig['args']) ? $mailConfig['args'] : array() );

        $r = new ReflectionClass($mailConfig['class']);


            $transport = $r->newInstanceArgs($args);


        if( !($transport instanceof Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract) ) {
          $transport = false;
        } 
      } catch( Exception $e ) {

        $transport = false;
        throw $e;
      }
```

`Amazonses_App_Mail_Transport_AmazonSES` carries `__construct`.But, fails to return `$transport = $r->newInstanceArgs($args);`

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried by replacing

```
$r = new ReflectionClass($mailConfig['class']);
$transport = $r->newInstanceArgs($args);
```

by

```
$className = $mailConfig['class'];
$transport = new $className($args);
```

I think it should work.